# CLSID_CNetworkListManager undeclared identifer - error

Tags: winapi, networking

I am developing an application to get the networks available on the system. Trying to run the same on windows vista. (The below code is based on the link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697388(VS.85).aspx)

Below is the Code Snippet:

```
#include "Netlistmgr.h"
#include "Objbase.h"


INetworkListManager* pNLM = NULL;
IEnumNetworks *pEnumNetworks = NULL;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CNetworkListManager,
  NULL,
  CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
  IID_INetworkListManager,
  (LPVOID*) &pNLM);
```

> error C2065:
>   'CLSID_CNetworkListManager' :
>   undeclared identifier

Kindly help... Have i missed any header files/Library files???

Thanks,
Suren

Answer (score 2):

[INetworkListManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370769(VS.85).aspx) comes with Vista and up, you need to make sure that you have  *#define WINVER=600* defined in your source before #include  or in the project settings.

You also need to make sure that you have [Platform SDK 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&displaylang=en) and up, if your working with Visual Studio 2008 then you're already using it.